# Using NASA's GIBS servers with GRASS GIS

Tags: wms, download, server, grass-7.2, nasa

I am trying to download WMS tiles into a grass mapset. I'd like to use NASA's GIBS servers which replaced the JPL OnEarth services. I'm not sure how much remains the same between the two services, but it seems that the JPL OnEarth server was supported. Here is an example command that I run in the Grass shell

```
r.in.wms url=https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/wmts.cgi layer=BlueMarble_ShadedRelief output=testing format=png
```

This does connect to and download from the server and it is reported that the raster is imported. However, the entire image is populated with no data. Am I missing something really basic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMS is not supported by [NASA's GIBS](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/about/science-system-description/eosdis-components/global-imagery-browse-services-gibs) server as far I can tell when going through their features.

> Features
>   Access imagery through standards-based web services and formats:
>   Web Map Tile Service (WMTS)
>   Tiled Web Map Service (TWMS)
>   Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
>   Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL)

Comment: In haste, I was assuming that WMS and WMTS would operate similarly. If you pass driver=WMTS_GRASS to r.in.wms, then you can access NASA's GIBS servers. Thanks for pointing that out.